# How to remove control Z characters from a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl, special-characters

File has control Z( ^Z) characters in them. I tried `sed 's/^Z//g' file_name` but not working. Even tried perl script but not removing them. Please let me know if there is way to remove this character.

Comment: Have a look at this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448413/remove-junk-character-g), the ascii code for "^Z" is "\032"

Answer (score 5):

The control character produced by <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> is `\032` in octal.  This can be deleted by `tr`:

```
tr -d '\032' <file >newfile
```

This deletes the characters anywhere in the file and creates a new file called `newfile` with the modified contents.

---

Your `sed` command does not work as the expression `^Z` would match a `Z` character at the start of the line. The `^` anchors the rest of the expression at the start of the line.

Comment: Note on calculating code for control characters. A is 1, B is 2 … Z is 26.

Answer (score 0):

You can match <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> using `\d` plus the decimal code of the character (in this case 26).

```
sed 's/\d26//g' < file > newfile
```

A "posix" alternative (in bash) could be something like:

```
sed $( echo 's/@//g' | tr '@' '\032' ) < file > newfile
```

The tr will replace '@' in regex with the carachter <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> (which code is 32 in octal).

Comment: Only with GNU `sed` though.

Comment: @Kusalananda, are you sure? `sed --posix 's/\d26//g' ` works.

Comment: With any other `sed` implementation, `s/\d26//g` would delete all instances of the literal string `d26`. Using `--posix` does _not_ disable extensions in GNU `sed`'s regular expression library.

Comment: Fascinating. @Kusalananda, you are right (as usual).

Comment: The second solution use both sed and tr when tr is good enougth by itself: `tr -d '\032' <file >newfile`.

Comment: @Isaac The second solution is an example with didactic intent. Sed is more "powerful" than tr. In this case is an overkill but, for more complex elaborations, it'd be useful.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ sed 's/\^Z//g' filename
```

**NOTE:** Special characters should be escaped with '\'.